Summation of Binomial Coefficients
The question
$$\binom{n}{0}\binom{n}{n} - \binom{n}{1}\binom{2n}{n}+\binom{n}{2}\binom{3n}{n}-\binom{n}{3}\binom{4n}{n}...$$
My approach
I tried writing the general term:
$$\sum_{r=1}^k \binom{n}{r-1}\binom{rn}{n} (-1)^{r-1}$$
I expanded it in factorials but I'm stuck.
$$\frac{n!}{(r-1)!(n-r+1)!}\frac{(rn)!}{(n!)(rn-n)!}(-1)^{r-1}$$
Any hints would be helpful. Thank you.

@abomasnow I don't know, it was a problem given by my teacher in high school. Is it not possible to write the sum?

Yes! Thank you! I don't think this is a telescoping sum either

Have you tried calculating $n = 1, 2, 3, 4$, and guessed the general form from there? That might give you ideas for how to proceed.

@CalvinLin I have written the general form

(I agree you wrote down the general term.) No, you're not understanding what I'm saying. I'm asking you to try small cases. For $n=1$, what is the sum? For $n=2$, what is the sum? For $n = 3$, what is the sum? For $n =4$, what is the sum? Now conjecture, for a given $n$, what could the sum be?

First hint: Calculate the expression for small values of $n$ to guess at the answer. $\quad$ Second hint: Clearly we have a PIE setup. What does $ { rn \choose n } $ represent, and how do we PIE it? $ \quad$ Now, generalize this expression to $ \sum (-1)^{n-k}{n \choose k } { mk \choose n} $ (Yours has $m = n$).

@CalvinLin sorry, but what does PIE stand for?

Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion. It's a summation with the term $ (-1)^r { n \choose r } $ in it.

Tabulating the value for small $n$, we observe that $ (-1)^nn^n$ matches the numerical answer. How can we show that it is indeed the answer?
We apply the complementary form of the Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion. Consider a $(n+1) \times n$ grid, with columns labeled $0, 1, \ldots n$, with exactly $n$ cells chosen. Let $A_i, i > 0$ be the event that column $i$ has no cells chosen.
Notice that $ \cap_{i=1}^n \bar{A_i}$ means that each of the columns $i > 0$ has at least 1 cell chosen. Since we have $n$ columns (with positive index) with at least 1 cell, and a total of $n$ cells chosen in the grid, thus each column has exactly 1 cell chosen, which clearly has size $n^n$.
The intersection of $n-k$ of these events $A_i$, means that we have to choose the cells from the other $k+1$ columns, which has size ${(k+1)n \choose n }$.
Thus,
$$ n^n = | \cap_{i=1}^n \bar{A_i} | = | S - \cup_{i=1}^n A_i|
\\ =|S| - \sum_{1\leq i \leq n} |A_i| + \sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq n} |A_i \cap A_j| - \ldots \\
= {(n+1)n \choose n  } - {n \choose 1}{n\cdot n \choose n  }+\ldots + (-1)^n {n\choose 0 }{ 1\cdot n \choose n}. $$

Notes

The more common (and simpler) problem is to show that

$$ m^n = \sum_{r=1}^n (-1)^{n-r} { n\choose r}{ rm \choose n}. $$
A similar PIE approach works, where we color $n$ cells in a $ m \times n$ grid.

@abomasnow: Snake Oil is a popular name for a technique presented in H. Wilf's book Generatingfunctionology. In fact the technique I use here is not the snake oil method, but a related one based on Egorychevs Method which is also shown in H. Wilf's book.

@abomasnow: Yes, a nice and clever way to popularise such techniques. :-)

@MarkusScheuer Oh interesting, I didn't realize they were different methods.

It is convenient to use the coefficient of operator $[z^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $z^n$ of a series. We can so write for example
\begin{align*}
[z^p](1+z)^q=\binom{q}{p}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
We obtain for $n\geq 0$:
\begin{align*}
\binom{n}{0}&\binom{n}{n} - \binom{n}{1}\binom{2n}{n}+\binom{n}{2}\binom{3n}{n}-\binom{n}{3}\binom{4n}{n}+\cdots\\
&=\color{blue}{\sum_{r=0}^n\binom{n}{r}\binom{(r+1)n}{n}(-1)^r}\tag{2}\\
&=\sum_{r=0}^n\binom{n}{r}[z^n](1+z)^{(r+1)n}(-1)^r\tag{3}\\
&=[z^n](1+z)^n\sum_{r=0}^n\binom{n}{r}(1+z)^{rn}(-1)^r\tag{4}\\
&=[z^n](1+z)^n\sum_{r=0}^n\binom{n}{r}\left(-\left(1+z\right)^n\right)^r\\
&=[z^n](1+z)^n\left(1-(1+z)^n\right)^n\tag{5}\\
&=[z^n](1+z)^n(-nz)^n\tag{6}\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=(-n)^n}\tag{7}
\end{align*}
Comment:

In (2) we note that the upper limit of the index can be set to $n$. Higher indices do not contribute since $\binom{n}{r}=0$ if $r>n$.

In (3) we use the coefficient of operator as stated in (1).

In (4) we use the linearity of the coefficient of operator and factor out $(1+z)^n$ as preparation for application of the binomial theorem.

In (5) we apply the binomial theorem.

In (6) we expand $(1-(1+z)^n)^n=(-nz-\cdots)^n$ and omit higher powers of $z$, since they don't contribute to $[z^n]$.

In (7) we select the coefficient of $z^n$ noting that only the constant term $1$ is to consider from $(1+z)^n$.



Nice and straightforward proof. (+1).

@MarkoRiedel: Many thanks, Marko. :-)
